# Hadoop JAVA_HOME not set when installation directory for java is the file system?

Tags: java, hadoop

I used [this tutorial to install java on Ubuntu 12.04](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-jdk-jre-in-ubuntu-12-04/);

I first tried installing it the old fashioned way by downloading java, adding a `JAVA_HOME` variable that points to the installation and adding it to the `PATH` concatenated with `\bin`) but that didn't work because of some strange openjdk that's installed by default...I remember being able to bypass it by using `update-alternatives` and picking the installation I downloaded, but it didn't work this time, my new installation was never detected by the command; so I ended up using that tutorial instead.

The only problem with using a PPA like in the tutorial, is that it doesn't install all of the jdk in a single directory that I can point `JAVA_HOME` to, and thus Hadoop complains that the variable is missing.

Is there anything that can be done about this to get Hadoop up and running?

Comment: What did u get in echo JAVA_HOME? @leeand00

Comment: I'm not sure that it actually matters...conf/hadoop-env.sh allows you to specify the JAVA_HOME variable to be used separate from the main one that may or may not be defined in .bashrc...(either that or it overrides it)

Answer (score 0):

When i installed i removed the openjdk and then installed java as usual. these are the steps i followed. hope it may help you

1. removed openjdk

   sudo apt-get purge openjdk-*
2. download java bin file appropriate to the OS(32bit/64bit)
3. change permissions

   chmod +x 6u -linux-x64.bin
4. to install the JDK into the current directory run the self-extracting binary. 
   Execute the downloaded file, prepended by the path to it. For example, if the file is in the current directory, prepend it with " ./" (necessary if " ." is not in the PATH environment variable):

   ./jdk-6u -linux-x64.bin
5. add JAVA_HOME Environment variable